# If I am building a custom app, does Salesforce handle the logins and security?

Tags: security, appexchange, app, session

I want to learn how to develop in salesforce so I can build custom apps that can do some statistical analysis on data.

I want to publish that app to the app exchange with the hopes that someone who has a salesforce subscription for their company can use that app to see the analysis on their own company's data.

**My concern is:** do I need to handle the logins like I would when I build a web applications- i.e. creating login pages, session handlers, GET vs. POST etc.?

I am thinking I might use Heroku and build the app using one of the supported languages [Java, PhP etc.]. **However, security is not my forte** and its something I'd rather let salesforce handle. Is a scenario I described possible with salesforce where I only need to concern with the core functionality of the app?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your app to appear as a "tab" inside Salesforce, you can use the [Canvas API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_framework_intro.htm). If you want them to authenticate with Salesforce in your own full-page application (such as the [Workbench](http://https:://workbench.developerforce.com/) does), you can use the [OAuth2 Web Server Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&language=en&type=0) to allow the user access to their data. In both cases, the user logs in to Salesforce and your app receives a session derived from that authentication. At no point do you directly need to get their username and password, deal with two-factor authentication, etc. Everything is handled for you. At that point, you can use whatever language you desire to build your app, since you'd just be using the regular REST or Chatter APIs (as appropriate).

Comment: I think I like that solution. I am thinking of leveraging the "visuals" from salesforce Wave or insert my own javascript objects [d3.js].

I guess there's a salesforce backend data model that my app will ideally consume? Is that how it works?

Comment: @NepzeTyson You have a [SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_intro.htm), [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/), [Chatter API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/), and [Wave API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_rest.meta/bi_dev_guide_rest/bi_rest_overview.htm) to access any data the user has access to, both regular and metadata (e.g. field types).

Answer (score 0):

Here you will get all the details [click here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/appexchange_publish.htm). You need to be a partnar salesforce will review your app before its go live

heroku is an another platform from which service can be consumed see pricing [here](https://www.heroku.com/pricing)